# How do I install Rigs of Rods?

Tags: installation, compiling

How do I install [Rigs of Rods](http://www.rigsofrods.com/) (open source vehicle simulator based on soft-body physics)?

I have compiled applications before like Gedit, Handbrake, XBMC but I can't seem to install/compile Rigs of Rods (and some of its dependencies). This proves to be quite the challenge for me.

I also read [Rigs of Rods wiki](http://www.rigsofrods.com/wiki/pages/Compiling_Sources_under_Linux) on how to compile in Linux but no luck. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is now a PPA so it's easy to install the program.

terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aapo-rantalainen/rigsofrods
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rigsofrods
```

You'll then need to download terrain and vehicle packs from the RoR site.

[source](http://handytutorial.com/install-rigs-of-rods-ubuntu-12-04-ppa/)

Comment: Can you explain how to add the PPA and then install RoR? This would help many new users.

Comment: This does not work anymore. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

### Install from old and abandoned PPA

[Aapo Rantalainen’s PPA](https://launchpad.net/~aapo-rantalainen/+archive/ubuntu/rigsofrods) appears to be abandoned but I could still get it to work based on the existing packages:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aapo-rantalainen/rigsofrods
sudo sed -i -e "s/ $(lsb_release -sc) / quantal /" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/aapo-rantalainen-rigsofrods-*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rigsofrods
```

### Install from the up-to-date upstream source code repository

Luckily *Rigs of Rods* provides a simple to use set of build and installation scripts targeting Ubuntu and other Debian-based Linux distributions.

1. Install Git and download build scripts and source code:

   ```
   sudo apt install git
   cd ~
   git clone https://github.com/RigsOfRods/ror-linux-buildscripts.git
   git clone -b 0.4.7.0 https://github.com/RigsOfRods/rigs-of-rods.git
   cd ror-linux-buildscripts
   ```
2. Follow the instructions in [`README.md`](https://github.com/RigsOfRods/ror-linux-buildscripts/blob/master/README.md) of the current directory:

   > #### Build and install Rigs of Rods
   >
   > ```
   > sh dependencies.sh
   > sh game.sh
   > ```
   >
   > #### Update to current snapshot
   >
   > ```
   > sh game.sh
   > ```

   For details see [`README.md`](https://github.com/RigsOfRods/ror-linux-buildscripts/blob/master/README.md).